# TYPO3 nocache for an specific page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've got a big TYPO3 page with a self coded plugin. Now I want that all stuff which is done in this extension isn't cached.

For example all the inputs were cached and when I reload the page all fields are prefilled

what can I do?

Comment: are you sure the prefill is done by your server and not from the browser?

Comment: I think so because when I resend the form I got an error Because session is used bevore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a extbase extension you write in ext_tables.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

// Plugin
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pluginname',
    array(
        'Plugin' => 'controller1',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Plugin' => 'controller1',
    )
);
```

Or disable cache in Page > Setting > Behaviour > Cache > Disable